# Read file memory is too large

Tags: c#

Is there a way to read the file without taking up too much memory?

I want to remove a range of bytes[] on the file. Then save it to another path.

```cs
using(FileStream sr = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sr))
    {
        abFile = new byte[(int)sr.Length];
        br.Read(abFile, 0, (int)sr.Length);
        br.Dispose();
    }
    sr.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at memory mapped files - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This really comes down to what are you doing in the read? Do you need the entire file in a byte array? What processing are you doing to the file data?

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, untick "Prefer 32-bit".  You don't prefer it with code like this.

Comment: _"Any way"_? -- sure, of course there's "any way". What have you tried? As others have mentioned, memory-mapped files is one approach some people take. You can also just process the parts of the file sequentially, a little bit at a time. Since you didn't explain anything about your files, nor why you want the entire contents in memory at once, nor what you've already tried in order to solve your problem, it's not possible to know what answer is good for you. The question is way too broad.

Comment: But, do take a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604900/sorting-gigantic-binary-files-with-c-sharp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874755/difficulty-reading-large-file-into-byte-array, and other Stack Overflow posts asking about large binary files.

Comment: I will also point out: the `using` statement is specifically there to make it easy to ensure disposable objects are disposed. There is no reason at all to call `Dispose()` on the object for the `using` statement inside that actual `using` statement's block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I am sorry for the fact that I did not explain the problem!

I want to remove a range of bytes[] on the file.
Then save it to another path.

Comment: And what do you know about that `range`?  Such details matter. There mighjt be a good answer about Seek() that you're not getting this way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to read the file without taking up too much memory?

Yes.

- Open the source file
- Open the destination file
- Start a loop
- Read a few kb
- Write a few kb, but skip writing the bytes you want to omit
- Repeat until the file is entirely written.